# Angular SVG Icon does not work with Angular Universal project lazy loading module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-universal, ng-modules

> Angular: 11.2.5
> Typescript: 4.0.2
> Angular-svg-icon: 11.2.0

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppHomeModule)[SvgIconRegistryService -> SvgIconRegistryService -> SvgLoader -> TransferState -> TransferState -> TransferState]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TransferState!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppHomeModule)[SvgIconRegistryService -> SvgIconRegistryService -> SvgLoader -> TransferState -> TransferState -> TransferState]:
```

**Component html:**

```
<svg-icon src="call.svg" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':90 }"></svg-icon>
```

**lazy-loaded module call:**

```
imports: [
   ...
   AngularSvgIconModule
],
```

**app.module.ts**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `BrowserTransferStateModule` on the client side (`app.module.ts`) and `ServerTransferStateModule` on the server side (`app.server.module.ts`)

Comment: Thanks for your lovely answer but why this information I did not get anywhere or missing any documentation ! 

I have few more lazy-loaded module missing or error, can you suggested me how can I  overcame all of those problem, except do question in Stack overflow. I am suffering by last 4/5days with multiple error for angular universal :(

Comment: There is no magical answer. Have a look there, it might help https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/gotchas.md

Answer (score 1):

From the angular-svg-icon [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon/v/11.2.0):

> BREAKING CHANGE: as of angular-svg-icon@9.0.0, an explicit call to forRoot() must be made on the module's import.

The angular-svg-icon should work as-is with webpack/angular-cli. Just import the AngularSvgIconModule and the HttpClientModule.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularSvgIconModule } from 'angular-svg-icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpClientModule, AngularSvgIconModule.forRoot() ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: forRoot() did the trick. Thanks for your help.